# 'self' implicit change previous data item in Python iteration

Tags: python, iteration, self

I have a question regarding the usage of **self** variable in Python. Please look at the following example:

```
from copy import deepcopy
class IntClass:
    props = {}
    def __init__(self, keys, values):
        indx = 0
        for key in keys:
            self.props[key] = values[indx]
            indx += 1
def display(self):
    for key in self.props.keys():
        print 'key=%s value=%s' %(key,self.props[key])

class IntGen:
    def gen(self, keys, values):
        for vs in values:
            yield [keys, vs]

    def start(self, keys, values):
        self.loader = self.gen(keys, values)

    def nextItem(self):
        return self.loader.next()

keys = ['k1', 'k2', 'k3']
values = [['v1.1', 'v1.2', 'v1.3'], ['v2.1', 'v2.2', 'v2.3'], ['v3.1', 'v3.2', 'v3.3']]

holder = []
intGen = IntGen()
intGen.start(keys, values)
while True:
    try:
        a = intGen.nextItem()
        holder.append(deepcopy(IntClass(a[0],a[1])))
    except StopIteration:
        break

for h in holder:
    h.display()
```

The result, as in my understanding, should be:

```
key=k3 value=v3.3
key=k2 value=v3.2
key=k1 value=v3.1
key=k3 value=v2.3
key=k2 value=v2.2
key=k1 value=v2.1
key=k3 value=v1.3
key=k2 value=v1.2
key=k1 value=v1.1
```

However, what I got is as follows:

```
key=k3 value=v3.3
key=k2 value=v3.2
key=k1 value=v3.1
key=k3 value=v3.3
key=k2 value=v3.2
key=k1 value=v3.1
key=k3 value=v3.3
key=k2 value=v3.2
key=k1 value=v3.1
```

It seems to me that within the While loop, when I try to create a new instance of IntClass, **that new instance has modified the values stored in props attribute of the instances created in the previous loop**, which at the end, cause the holder contains all instances with the same data.

Anyone can point me to the answer? Look like there is something wrong with **self** variable but I have no glue on how to fix it.

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Why are you using a `while` loop to loop over an iterator? Use a `for` loop.

Comment: To clarify: Just add an `__iter__()` method that returns `self.loader` and then use a for loop (for better yet in this case, a list comprehension - this cuts 6 lines of code down to 1.). It's also worth noting that when you have an iterator and want the next value, it's better practice to use the `next()` builtin than `iterator.next()` (which becomes `iterator.__next__()` in 3.x).

Comment: @Lattyware: since I use a generator to load data which sequentially yields each data instance for processing. It should be fine with **while** loop to read data until end. Different from generator, an iterator loads the whole bunch of data items at once..

Comment: You are misinformed. A generator is a type of iterator. You can loop over a generator as in your example with a for loop while still keeping it lazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put the line `props = {}` directly in the class definition. This will cause all instances of the class to share the same dictionary.

If you want each instance to have its own dictionary, put `self.props = {}` in `__init__` instead.

Comment: Thanks @interay, it works. Also, could you point me to the Python documentation about this case, I probably did not pay enough attention though.